# Avoiding re-evaluation and dynamically unloading objects called with `require`

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

i'm studying how nodejs module system works.

I've found so far this literature:

1. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html
2. http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/
3. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

It helps me to understand a few points however is still have these questions:

- If i have a expensive resource (let's say database pooling connection) inside a module, how can i make sure that by requiring the module again i am not re-evaluating the resource?
- How can i dynamically unload a disposable resource once i already called the 'require' on it?

It's important because i have some scenarios that demands me to make sure that i have a single instance of database pool. because of this i'm exporting modules which are able to receive parameters instead of just require the expensive resource.

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: It depends on where the resource is created within the module. If it's created in the module's own/top scope, [it will exist once per `node` process](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). If the resource is created within a `function` in the module, it will be created every time that function is invoked, regardless of Node's module system (unless the function is defined to [memoize its arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

Comment: You can find this information out yourself by creating modules and using `console.log` to observe the output and when things are evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alon Salont has written an EXCELLENT guide to understanding `exports` in NodeJS (which is what you're accessing when you call `require()`) here:
http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/export-this/#singleton

If you study the list of options for what a module can export, you'll see that the answer to your question depends on how the module is written. When you call `require`, NodeJS will look for the module loaded in its cache and return it if it already had it loaded elsewhere.

That means if you choose to export a Singleton pattern, are monkey-patching, or creating global objects (I recommend only the first one in your case), only ONE shared object will be created / will exist. Singleton patterns are good for things like database connections that you want to be shared by many modules. Although some argue that "injecting" these dependencies via a parent/caller is better, this is a philosophical view not shared by all, and singletons are widely used by software developers for shared-service tasks like this.

If you export a function, typically a constructor, `require()` will STILL return just one shared reference to that. However, in this case, the reference is to a function, not something the function returns. `require()` doesn't actually CALL the function for you, it just gives you a reference to it. To do any real work here, you must now call the function, and that means each module that `requires` this thing will have its own instance of whatever class the module provides. This pattern is the more traditional one where a class instance is desired / is the goal. Most NPM modules fit this category, although that doesn't mean a singleton is a bad idea in your case.